# Need help in connecting two tables without exactly the same info in the joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `articles` and `log`

the articles table has these columns

- `title` represents whole name of article
- `slug` represents shorter version of the name

example

```
title                                    | slug
-----------------------------------------|----------------------------
cats are cute and wonderfully adorable   | cats-are-cute
```

`log` table has columns:

```
path                          |  id 
------------------------------|--------
/article/cats-are-cute        |  123
```

- `path` represents the slug but with a start of `'/article/'` and also has some empty values
- `id` represents the user id that has read that article

I need a query to find What are the most popular three articles of all time

I tried this

```
select articles.title, count(log.id) as views
from articles
    right join log on log.path like concat('/article/',articles.slug)
group by articles.title
order by views desc limit 3;
```

it doesn't show correct values.

both answers below are correct, but the one i chose takes less processing time

Comment: I think you want a `left join` not a right join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `LIMIT` plus `CONCAT` rules out everything except for MySQL to my knowledge.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: that would work on Postgres just as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT articles.title, tmp.views
FROM   (SELECT path, Count(path) AS views
        FROM   log
        GROUP  BY path) tmp
       INNER JOIN articles ON tmp.path = Concat('/article/', articles.slug)
ORDER  BY tmp.views DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

Comment: this query returns one top views article repeated 3 times

Comment: Is the above table structure correct? - [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46c94/1/0) is a demo.

Comment: Glad to hear it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to check if the `slug` column of the `articles` table is contained within the `path` of the `log` table.  We can try using a POSIX regex in Postgres to handle that:

```
SELECT
    a.title,
    COUNT(l.id) AS views
FROM articles a
LEFT JOIN log l
    ON l.path ~ CONCAT('.*\y', a.slug, '\y.*')
GROUP BY
    a.title
ORDER BY
    views DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This would match any path which contains, as an exact path component, the slug from the corresponding article.

Comment: It's Quite better organized than my query, still no correct values displayed. i want the quary to check only if the slug is exactly in the path, and if anyletter is after the slug it shouldn't take it     as example    path:/article/cats-are-cute  is correct, but path :/article/cats-are-cutem isn't correct

Comment: I don't doubt it :-) ... let us know if the answer helped or not.

Comment: Then use my second option with `REGEXP`.  That would check if `cats-are-cute` exists as an exact path element, somewhere in the path.

Comment: I updated the answer for Postgres.  In the future, please always tag with your exact database.

Comment: unfortunaterly it shows the same previous result, and matches with /articles/cats-are-cutedfhjjgdfh

Comment: That shouldn't be happening, because I place word boundaries around the slug (`\y`).  Can you post a demo link here?

Comment: works great ! but takes quite big time to gather results thanks

Comment: The problem is perhaps your table design which requires the use of regex in this way.  In general, invoking regex is a costly operation, especially when it is the join condition.